# C# Importing Image Coordinates from C++ cfg file

Tags: c#, c++

I have a cfg C++ file Contains this code

```
CreateObjectType("Namoo", "Unit")
{
  MapObj()
  {
    TypeDisplay()
    {
      Image()
      {
        Image("if_game_portraits.tga", 210, 168, 42, 42);
        Mode("Centre");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to import this coordinates?

```
Image("if_game_portraits.tga", 210, 168, 42, 42);
```

(x=210,y=168,width=42,height=42)

to 
DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
                                 new Rectangle(x, y, width, height),
                                 GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

N.B: sometimes the code looks like this

```
TypeDisplay()
{
  Image("if_game_portraits.tga", 210, 168, 42, 42);
}
```

Comment: What are all these methods and types?

Comment: I edited the Questions clear now?

Comment: What is a C++ cfg file? That's not C++ code.

Comment: I got this cfg file from a game base language is C++

Comment: Army Men RTS, anyway could I read cfg file Image() coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the exact structure of your input file, you can just treat it as a text file, and find the line (or lines?) that you are interested in. In the simplest case, that could look something like this:

```
var allInputLines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToInputFile);
var relevantLine = allInputLines.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Contains("Image(\"if_game_portraits.tga"));
if (relevantLine != null)
{
    char[] separator = { ',', ')' };
    var fragments = relevantLine.Split(separator);
    if (fragments.Count() == 6)  //make sure that the line looks like we expect
    {
        if (int.TryParse(fragments[1], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var x)
            && int.TryParse(fragments[2], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var y)
            && int.TryParse(fragments[3], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var w)
            && int.TryParse(fragments[4], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var h))
        {
            //do something with x,y,w,h:
            //...
        }                    
    }
}
```

Of course, if you have more variance in your input, you may have to adjust the criteria accordingly. But hopefully you don't need anything like a full-fledged C++-parser.

Comment: I tryied to add `richTextBox1.Text` for `allInputLines` but Error